# Calculate the sum of one dynamic table after remove one item in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a dynamic table generated by PHP code:

```
   $grand_total=0;
   $sql1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cart")
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){

      $id=$row['id'];
      $unit_price=$row['unit_price'];
      $qty=$row['qty'];

      $total_price=$unit_price*$qty;
      $grand_total=$grand_total+$total_price;

      $output .='<tr id="$id">';
      $output .='<td>'.$unit_price.'</td>';
      $output .='<td>'.$qty.'</td>';
      $output .='<td>'.$total_price.'</td>';
      $output .='<td align="center"><img class="delete" src="images/Erase.png" alt="" width="16" height="16" rel="'.$total_price.'" /></td>';
      $output .='</tr>';

   }
   $output .='<tr>';
   $output .='<td colspan="2"> TOTAL </td>';
   $output .='<td>'.$grand_total.'</td'>;
   $output .='</tr>';
```

When the user click on the image to Delete one item, it calls jQuery function:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#table2 td img.delete').click(function(){
        if (confirm("Do you want to delete this item?")) {

          var parent = $(this).closest('TR');
          var id = parent.attr('id');
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "id=" +id,
            url: "packages_cart_delete.php"
          });
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    alert("Item has been deleted!");
}
return false;

    });
});

</script>
```

The HTML output:

```
<table id="table2" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellspadding="3">
   <tr>
      <th>Unit Price</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Total Price</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
  </tr>
  <?php echo $output; ?>
</table>
```

It is working very good. The only thing missing and that I can't get through is how to calculate the `$grand_total` variable automatically without refresh the whole page right after the item is erased.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
      $output .='<td>'.$total_price.'</td>';
```

to

```
      $output .='<td class="total-price">'.$total_price.'</td>';
```

And change

```
   $output .='<td>'.$grand_total.'</td'>;
```

to

```
   $output .='<td class="grand-total">'.$grand_total.'</td'>;
```

And call the following function after the deletion is successful:

```
function calculateTotal() {
    var grandTotal = 0;
    $(".total-price").each( function() {
        var thisPrice = parseInt( $(this).text() );
        grandTotal += thisPrice;
    });
    $(".grand-total").text( grandTotal );
}
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify your js a bit as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#table2 td img.delete').click(function(){
        if (confirm("Do you want to delete this item?")) {

          var parent = $(this).closest('TR');
          var id = parent.attr('id');
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "id=" +id,
            url: "packages_cart_delete.php"
          });

          var ttlprice = parseInt( $(this).attr("rel"), 10 ); // item price
          var $grand = $("#table2 > tr:last-child > td:last-child"); // grand total
          $grand.text( parseInt( $grand.text(), 10 ) - ttlprice ); // subtracted

          $(this).parent().parent().remove();
          alert("Item has been deleted!");
        }
        return false;

    });
});
```

You can simplyfy this a bit with cyber_rookie's suggestion of adding classes to your table, specifically,

```
$output .='<td class="grand-total">'.$grand_total.'</td'>;
```

which would make it

```
var ttlprice = parseInt( $(this).attr("rel"), 10 ); // item price
var $grand = $('.grand-total'); // grand total
$grand.text( parseInt( $grand.text(), 10 ) - ttlprice ); // subtracted
```

Comment: Thanks for the improvement @DomDay